# How do I create and save a set/array of objects for a given Core Data entity?

Tags: arrays, object, core-data, swift3

I have an app that will ideally compare luxury restaurants and their respective dishes against each other. This means I have a Core Data entity called `Restaurant` with attributes like `restaurantName`, `location`, `averagePrice`, and `foodType`. I have a second Core Data entity called `MenuItem` with attributes like `foodName`, `caloryCount`, `price`, and `rating`.

Since the goal is to compare, say, two steakhouses and their filet mignons on calories/price/rating, I'd really like to take a preloaded list of `MenuItem` objects I have (an array called `selectedMenuItems`) and somehow save that as an attribute of the `Restaurant` entity so that each individual restaurant will have an instance of those menu item objects attached to it (after which the user could edit the calories/price/rating for each menu item on a restaurant by restaurant basis). In the most ideal scenario, if anything was added or subtracted from the `selectedMenuItems` array of objects it would be reflected across all individual restaurants.

What I've tried so far:

**1.) Many-to-many relationship between `Restaurant` and `MenuItem`**

As you can probably guess from my above description, this didn't work out how I wanted it to since it only connected each restaurant to the `selectedMenuItems` array, and any alterations made in a restaurant propagated through the relationship to the array (this was a fundamental misunderstanding of relationships, on my part).

**2.) Create an attribute of type Transformable in `Restaurant` to hold the `selectedMenuItems` array**

This looked like it was going to work for a moment. As I said, I created an attribute called `menuItems` in my `Restaurant` entity of type Transformable, and then in the view controller for each restaurant's detail view (the view controller that displays the `menuItems` is an additional navigation step) I added the following inside of `viewDidLoad()`:

```
// The selected Restaurant is passed from the prior screen to restaurant
restaurant.menuItems = selectedMenuItems as NSObject?
```

Which resulted in seemingly what I needed, except for the fact that if I made any changes to the `selectedMenuItems` array, it would cause the app to crash with the console readout `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Restaurant encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

**3.) Break apart the `selectedMenuItems` array of *objects* into matched arrays of *properties***

After doing some experimenting with 2.), it appeared as though having an array of objects was the issue. Because of this, I iterated through `selectedMenuItems` and stripped out the properties into their own arrays (`foodNameArray`, `caloryCountArray`, `priceArray`, etc.). After that, I assigned each of those to newly created attributes of my `Restaurant` entity:

```
    restaurant.foodNames = foodNameArray as NSObject?
    restaurant.caloryCounts = caloryCountArray as NSObject?
    restaurant.prices = priceArray as NSObject?
```

Now, this was already looking very dodgy and prone to catastrophic failure. It did, however, work pretty much how I wanted it to. The issue here was that any changes to `selectedMenuItems` (like adding/removing a new object) didn't pass through to my restaurants after the first load. This is in contrast with 1.) where the changes propagated from the restaurants to `selectedMenuItems` (bottom to top) compared to 3.), where I want the changes to flow top to bottom.

Given the above descriptions, does anyone have advice on how I can get the functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a many-many relationship, I would use three entities:

- `Restaurant`, as you currently have;
- `Dish`, which represents the generic menu item, such as "Filet mignon" or "Rib-eye"; and
- `MenuItem`, which is a particular `Dish` served by a particular `Restaurant`.

Because `Dish` is generic, it would have only one attribute `foodName` (though you might want others).  `MenuItem` would have attributes `caloryCount`, `price`, `rating`.

Since each `MenuItem` represents a particular dish served by a particular restaurant, it would have "to-one" relationships to `Restaurant` and `Dish`.  For each relationship, the inverse would be "to-many": a Restaurant will serve many `MenuItems`, and a `Dish` could feature in many  `MenuItems`.

You can then preload the list of Dishes, from which users can select those which are served by a particular restaurant.  You can then create corresponding `MenuItems` and can presumably let users record calories/price/rating.  If the user deletes a MenuItem, the corresponding Dish is unaffected, so will be available for other existing and/or new Restaurants.  If the user wants to add a MenuItem for which there is no existing Dish, you can add a new Dish, which will then be available for any subsequent MenuItems.

Comment: This sounds incredibly promising, thanks so much for the thorough answer! I will take a swing at this later tonight after work, and if it's functioning correctly I'll mark your answer as solving my issue.

Comment: I didn't have the time to fully set everything up and test, but I think this is exactly what I was looking for. You're a life saver, thanks so much!